# How can I send an Image directly to WhatsApp Status? using Ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

Can I use [Social Sharing](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) to share an image directly to WhatsApp?

I'am use Ionic Framework.

Or is there any alternative?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: The plugin description says you can share to watsapp too.
`<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp('Message via WhatsApp', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})">msg via WhatsApp (with errcallback)</button>
`. You tried this?

Comment: Yes I did, then the user can choose status or contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately you cant do directly with Ionic, because the Social Share plugin dont have acces to the whatsapp core (i think theres no app to do that directly). Btw, you can share the image with the common method of Social Share, and when you pick the contacts, you can pick "Status" to share in.

[image: You can choose status when share]

Comment: I  know it, but I'm looking for a way to do it direkly. Is there no other way?

Comment: No, because whatsapp dont have an open Api to acces to status function directly. With Java you can do some tricks, but with ionic, at least for now, its not possible.